# AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, pandas

Could anyone please help me with why I am getting the below error, everything worked before when I used the same logic, after I converted my data type of date columns to the appropriate format.

Below is the line of code I am trying to run

```
data['OPEN_DT'] = data['OPEN_DT'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d') if len(x[:x.find ('-')]) == 4 else datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Error being received :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-f0a22bfffeee> in <module>
----> 1 data['OPEN_DT'] = data['OPEN_DT'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d') if len(x[:x.find ('-')]) == 4 else datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y'))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3846             else:
   3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3849 
   3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-93-f0a22bfffeee> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 data['OPEN_DT'] = data['OPEN_DT'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d') if len(x[:x.find ('-')]) == 4 else datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y'))

AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'find'
```

ValueError: time data '30/09/2020' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'
Many thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `data['OPEN-DT']` column?

Comment: data['OPEN_DT'] = data['OPEN_DT'].replace(np.nan,'0001-01-01')

data['OPEN_DT'] = data['OPEN_DT'].astype(str)

this was previous code before trying the above

Answer (score 0):

x is timestamp you should convert it to str then look for '-' in it:

```
str(x).find('-')
```

And Why don't you simply use `infer_time_format` to automatically detect the format by pandas?

Answer (score 0):

as ValueError is showing - %d-%m-%Y this needs to be changed to %d/%m/%Y to read date - 30/09/2020.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
data = {}
dates = {'27/09/2020', '28/09/2020', '29/09/2020', '30/09/2020'}
data['OPEN_DT'] = pd.Series(list(dates))
data['OPEN_DT'] = data['OPEN_DT'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%Y/%m/%d') if len(x[:str(x).find ('-')]) == 4 else datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'))
print(data)
```